# Google Document List API and Google Drive SDK

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

What is the roadmap for DOcument List Api? It has more functions (i.e. ACL) than Google Drive SDK. Now Sample for JAVA or PHP have dissapeared from documentations. Is it going to be deprecated in the near future?

Answer (score 5):

Currently, the Documents List API is an API that is related to the Google Drive SDK, and it can be used to access the same data. We plan in the future that the Drive API itself will directly contain all the functionality of the Documents List API.

Sorry for the somewhat vague answer, but we don't give specific promises about timelines and future products.

Comment: I'd just +1 that an index api endpoint directly in Drive would be superb and solve many problems I'm facing in Ruby.