# Google Drive vs Google Doc for iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-docs-api, google-drive-api

I have an iOS app that uses the Google Docs List API to access and download spreadsheet data.  I've done a basic test with upgrading my Google Docs account to Google Drive, and everything still seems to be working okay.

Based on the answer for this question [Google Document List API and Google Drive SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320123/google-document-list-api-and-google-drive-sdk) it looks like things will continue to work for awhile.

Are there any steps that mobile devs should be taking now to move to the new API?  My main concern is that most of the developer docs so far are related to web apps and not mobile apps so requirements like registering for the chrome web store don't seem to fit.  For example:

"Warning: Apps will not have any API access to files unless the app has been installed in Chrome Web Store. To test an app during development, you must first create a listing and install it."

Any guidance or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this answer for the rationale behind the Chrome Web Store installation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10476737/186674

Also, we are considering removing the installation requirement for the development and testing phase, we should have some updates soon.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still not sure what, if anything, I need to start doing to migrate to Google Drive since currently everything still works using the Google Docs API.

Comment: The two APIs access the same resources so you probably don't need to migrate if you only want to save and load files from Drive/Docs. The real use case for the Drive API is to integrate with the Drive UI and extend it with an app that can deal with some specific file types, e.g. Autocad WS allowing to work on dwg files from inside Drive.

Answer (score 0):

iOS apps using the Documents List API should now update to using the Google Drive API and the newer [Google APIs Client Library for Objective-C](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/).

The new API and library are quite a bit easier to use and more efficient than are the older GData alternatives.